# Git command to get all files under a specific directory and hash

Tags: git

I am trying to get all the files under a specific directory using git. I am using `git rev-parse origin/master` to get the master branch hash. I now want to use this hash to get all the files under a specific directory.

I am able to get all the files using the command `git ls-tree -r masterhash --name-only --full-tree` but wondering if there is a better way for a specific directory.

Comment: Is there something wrong with the command you have shown?

Comment: And what does this have to do with Python?

Comment: @mkrieger1 The command I posted gives me all the files under the specified hash. I want the files under a specific hash and a specific directory. Reg python, I am doing these operations in a python app.

Comment: Why did you use `--full-tree`? Did you try omitting it, or specifying a specific directory instead?

Comment: Any place that takes a hash ID usually takes a name that resolves to a hash ID too, so you can just run `git ls-tree -r origin/master`, for instance.

Comment: And `git ls-tree` also accepts paths.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a specific tree for a specific revision with a syntax like this: `HEAD:sha256`.  That refers to the tree object at the `HEAD` revision in the directory `sha256` (e.g., for the Git project repository).

If you want to get only the names, you can do this:

```
$ git ls-tree --name-only -r HEAD:sha256
block/sha256.c
block/sha256.h
gcrypt.h
```

If you want the path relative to the root of the repository, then write this:

```
% git ls-tree --name-only -r HEAD sha256
sha256/block/sha256.c
sha256/block/sha256.h
sha256/gcrypt.h
```

You don't need `--full-name` or `--full-tree` unless you believe that you'll be operating in a subdirectory and don't want to be restricted to that subdirectory.  Additionally, while I've specified `HEAD` here, you can use any revision pattern you like (see `gitrevisions(7)`).